# Email Error On Website

Tags: email, contact-us, contact-form, magento2.2.8

I am getting this error on our website

> 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user Email

Just to make you aware email 1 is different to email 2

Any advice on resolving this would be great.

Comment: email 1 is different to email 2 on website, admin user or customer?

Comment: Email 1 is different to email 2 on the website.

Answer (score 0):

As website I believe you are either going to have to experiment with the following setting:

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/email-communications.html

- On the Admin sidebar, tap Stores. Then under Settings, choose Configuration.
- In the panel on the left under Advanced, choose System.
- Expand the Mail Sending Settings section. Then, do the following:
- Set Return Path to 'Yes' or 'Specified'

  - No - (Recommended Security Measure Routes returned email to the default store email address.
  - Yes - Routes returned email to the default store email address.
  - Specified - Routes returned email to the email address specified in the Return Path Email field.

or use extension

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/

Comment: Thank you. I gave that a go, and still no success. Will continue to investigate.